# Symfony 2 deployment - cache handling

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine

I'm following the instructions at this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html) to deploy my symfony2 application.

My question is strictly related to STEP D

> D) Clear your Symfony Cache Make sure you clear (and warm-up) your
>   Symfony cache:

```
$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

When I run that command, all symfony cache is cleared, including doctrine cache.
My application highly relies on doctrine cached data, so I was wondering if there is a way to avoid clearing the doctrine cache every-time I deploy. For example, I could be deploying only some small bug fixes in the application code, is it necessary to clear the cache every time? What would happen if I don't clear the cache after a minor bug fix?

Just to add some more context, my main issue is with doctrine cache. Because doctrine cache is stored inside the main symfony cache folder, and cache:clear dumps that folder, I lose my doctrine cache too. If I could separate doctrine cache from the main cache folder (setup a custom path) that would solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use a automatic deployment system as [Capifony](http://capifony.org/) that is really simple to setup and creates "releases".

That means that when you deploy, the application is stored into a new standalone folder, the vendors are installed, the assets are dumped and the cache is cleared. This folder is used for production only when these process are done, so you doesn't have any down-time

Comment: I'm actually using automated deployment with ansible (which I believe is kind of similar to Capifony). I like the idea of a standalone folder, I need to look more into it. This could work.

Comment: Alternatively, I'm wandering if it's possible to separate doctrine cache from the symfony cache. Like give doctrine cache a separate path rather than storing it under the main symfony cache folder. That would probably fix my issue. Because as I understand from symfony docs, when I clear the cache, the "cache" folder is dumped, and my doctrine cache resides in a subfolder inside that cache folder. So if I could store doctrine cache outside the main cache folder, maybe it wouldn't be affected when clearing the cache. I don't know if it's possible though

Comment: I'm not sure about this, it is wrong to share the cache between two version of your app, I really think the good solution is to deploy into a standalone server then switch when the build process (asset dump, cache warmup...) is totally done

Comment: So does your solution involve 2 separate servers? Or can I achieve this with only 1 server and separate standalone folders?

Comment: I misspelled myself, I ment "deploy into a standalone folder*", not "server" sorry

Answer (score 0):

It's highly recommended to clear the cache every time. For example, you create a new class you depend on. If you don't clear the cache, autoloader won't load your new class. Of course, only in production mode because dev has a bit different autoloading logic.

However, there's no single answer on your question - there are some issues on application acting connected with cache "freshness". You have definitely to clear it on database/entity structure change, routes and classes structure, annotations, configuration. In prod env, they are preprocessed to improve performance - after caching, the original values (config/routes) are unused till the next cache clearing.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. If I don't clear the cache during deployment, I could have some issues with my app. I'm wandering if it's possible to separate doctrine cache from the symfony cache. Like give doctrine cache a separate path rather than storing it under the main symfony cache folder. That would probably fix my issue.

Comment: The only thing I came across right now is to create own ``query_cache_driver``, ``metadata_cache_driver``, ``result_cache_driver`` (for example, extending stock ones) changing your directory.

Answer (score 0):

When you do some design fix for example you don't need to clear all cache. You can go to the cache directory and manualy delete only those cache files that you want to remove and leave Doctrine cache untouched.

Comment: Makes sense, but I have automated deployment with ansible, so I was looking for a more consistent approach rather than having to worry everytime about what files to remove